# What do i put in the "handler" prop of aws-cdk's gateway.LambdaRestApi?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm building out one of my first gateway api's and have been reading the code and documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html#aws-lambda-backed-apis).

For an `apigateway` which use made using the `LambdaRestApi` function, my understanding was that i define the endpoints and the lambda attached to the endpoints.

If that's the case, what do i put as the functions `handler` function? I don't have any plans for there to be a base route for it so do i have to just have a blank lambda here? Or am i going in the wrong direction with my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LambdaRestApi`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/f61d950aaeba13bd6501b7c8971a9115f4a53f08/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/lambda-api.ts#L51) is just a utility construct based on `RestApi` with  `defaultIntegration` to a Lambda function.

You can use a plain [`RestApi`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html) instead if you don't need the default proxy integration to a Lambda handler configured.